# Avoid duplicating nested objects in redux store

Tags: redux, reducers, redux-orm

I'm giving [redux-orm](https://github.com/tommikaikkonen/redux-orm) a try and from what I can gather, redux-orm creates an object in store, whose key is the value specified via `Model.name`, for every registered model.

Well,to create my "entities" reducer, I'm using **combineReducers**, passing in the reducers for all my entities, like this:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import City from './cityReducer';
import Poi from './pointOfInterestReducer';

const entitiesReducer = combineReducers({
  City,
  Poi
});

export default entitiesReducer;
```

[image]

And finally this is how I create my `rootReducer`, also using `combineReducers`:

[image]

The problem is that,***I think that***, by using `combineReducers` I'm duplicating the keys in my store like it's shown here:

[image]

Do you have any idea how I can avoid this, and have all my models be direct descendants of "entities"?

Something like `entities>City` and not `entities>City>City`

### Edit: cityReducer.js

```
import orm from './../../orm/orm';
import * as types from '../../actions/actionTypes';

const loadCities = (state, action) => {
  // Create a Redux-ORM session from our entities "tables"
  const session = orm.session(state);
  // Get a reference to the correct version of model classes for this Session
  const { City } = session;
  const { cities } = action.payload;

  // Clear out any existing models from state so that we can avoid
  // conflicts from the new data coming in if data is reloaded

  City.all().toModelArray().forEach(city => city.delete());


  // Immutably update the session state as we insert items
  cities.forEach(city => City.parse(city));  
  return session.state;
};

const updateCity = (state, payload) => {
  const { id, newItemAttributes } = payload;

  const session = orm.session(state);
  const { City } = session;

  if (City.hasId(id)) {
    const modelInstance = City.withId(id);

    modelInstance.update(newItemAttributes);
  }

  return session.state;
};


const deleteCity = (state, payload) => {
  const { id } = payload;

  const session = orm.session(state);
  const { City } = session;

  if (City.hasId(id)) {
    const modelInstance = City.withId(id);

    // The session will immutably update its state reference
    modelInstance.delete();
  }

  return session.state;
};

const createCity = (state, payload) => {
  const { city } = payload;

  const session = orm.session(state);
  const { City } = session;

  City.parse(city);

  return session.state;
};

const citiesReducer = (dbState, action) => {
  const session = orm.session(dbState);
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.LOAD_CITIES_SUCCESS: return loadCities(dbState, action);
    case types.CREATE_CITY_SUCCESS: return createCity(dbState, action);
    case types.UPDATE_CITY_SUCCESS: return updateCity(dbState, action);
    case types.DELETE_CITY_SUCCESS: return deleteCity(dbState, action);
    default: return session.state;
  }
};

export default citiesReducer;
```

Comment: plz share City Reducer

Comment: Done! Please see the edit.

Answer (score 1):

There's two ways you can use Redux-ORM to define its "tables" structure, and write reducer logic to use those tables.  I gave examples of both approaches in my blog posts [Practical Redux, Part 1: Redux-ORM Basics](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2016/10/practical-redux-part-1-redux-orm-basics/), [Practical Redux, Part 2: Redux-ORM Concepts and Techniques](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2016/10/practical-redux-part-2-redux-orm-concepts-and-techniques/), and [Practical Redux, Part 5: Loading and Displaying Data](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2016/12/practical-redux-part-5-loading-and-displaying-data/).  (Note that those posts cover use of Redux-ORM 0.8, and version 0.9 has some API changes.  I listed those changes in [Practical Redux, Part 9](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/07/practical-redux-part-9-managing-dependencies/).)

The first approach is to write your reducer logic attached to your model classes, and use the Redux-ORM `ORM` instance to generate a reducer that creates the "tables" and manages them for you.  Per [the example on the front of the Redux-ORM repo](https://github.com/tommikaikkonen/redux-orm):

```
import {createReducer} from "redux-orm";
import {orm} from "./models";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    entities: createReducer(orm)
});
```

The other approach is to write your own function that creates the initial state, and possibly other functions that handle the updating:

```
import {orm} from "./models";

const initialState = orm.getEmptyState();

export default function entitiesReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    // handle other actions here if desired
    return state;
}
```

In other words, don't define the separate per-model-type "tables" yourself.  Let Redux-ORM define those, either automatically in its own reducer, or by using it to generate the initial state for your entities reducer.